# Google script - transfer to other tab in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to transfer specific cells in a row when in a certain cell a specific value is detected.

I have following script, but when I have more then 1 row that meets the value, the data isn't transferred properly.

```
var MASTERSHEET_ID = '162gDqlIC0YZRS6C4PoXnhKFMoe3O9estj1avTZgi34M';

function PUSHrondleiding()  {

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MASTERSHEET_ID).getSheetByName('Rondleidingen');
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MASTERSHEET_ID).getSheetByName('Kandidaten');
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++)
  {
     var rowData = data[i];
     if (rowData[8] == "Ja" && rowData [9] =="")
     {sourceSheet.getRange(i+1, 10).setValue(today);NieuweKANDIDAAT();PUSHRondleiding1();PUSHRondleiding2();destSheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(today)
     }
  }    
}


function NieuweRONDLEIDING() {
  var sheetAANVRAAG = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Rondleidingen');
  sheetAANVRAAG.getRange('A6:J6').activate();
  sheetAANVRAAG.insertRowsBefore(sheetAANVRAAG.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  sheetAANVRAAG.getRange('A5:J5').activate().copyTo(sheetAANVRAAG.getRange('A6'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  sheetAANVRAAG.getRange('A6').setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy"));
//  sheetKAND.getRange('X3').setValue('={"F1 AFSLUIT";arrayformula(if(R4:R=TRUE;"HIDE";if(S4:S=TRUE;"HIDE";"nihil")))}');
//  sheetKAND.getRange('Y3').setValue('={"F2 NUMMER";arrayformula(if(A4:A="";"";A4:A))}');
  //sheetKAND.getRange('M5').insertCheckboxes();
  
  sheetAANVRAAG.getRange('A6').activate();
                       
};

function PUSHRondleiding1() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var master = ss.getSheetByName('Rondleidingen');
  var colWidth = 4;//Number of columns to copy from master
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName('Kandidaten'); //Destination sheet
  var selectedfirstRow = ss.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();  // neemt de rijnummer van de actieve cel
  var goeieKandidaat = master.getRange(selectedfirstRow,2,4,colWidth); // capteert vanaf gegeven range= rijnum., kolomnum., # rijen, # kolommen)
  var Starter = master.getRange(selectedfirstRow,1,1,4); // capteert vanaf gegeven range= rijnum., kolomnum., # rijen, # kolommen)
  var templateLijn = dest.getRange('A5:Y5')
templateLijn.copyTo(dest.getRange('A6:Y6'));
dest.getRange('C6:F6').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
goeieKandidaat.copyTo(dest.getRange('C6:F6'),{contentsOnly: true});
    }

function PUSHRondleiding2() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var master = ss.getSheetByName('Rondleidingen');
  var colWidth = 1;//Number of columns to copy from master
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName('Kandidaten'); //Destination sheet
  var selectedfirstRow = ss.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();  // neemt de rijnummer van de actieve cel
  var goeieKandidaat = master.getRange(selectedfirstRow,7,7,colWidth); // capteert vanaf gegeven range= rijnum., kolomnum., # rijen, # kolommen)
  var Starter = master.getRange(selectedfirstRow,7,7,1); // capteert vanaf gegeven range= rijnum., kolomnum., # rijen, # kolommen)
  
  var templateLijn = dest.getRange('G6:G6')

templateLijn.copyTo(dest.getRange('G6:G6'));

dest.getRange('G6:G6').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

goeieKandidaat.copyTo(dest.getRange('G6:G6'),{contentsOnly: true}); `   

    }`
```

Data doesn't transfer in the correct row. I tried to put the code in several subfunction to make it transparant, but I can't see what the problem is and why the rows are mixed up

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from `I would like to transfer specific cells in a row when in a certain cell a specific value is detected.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Can you support your question with some images?